# Why is omitting "who" correct?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, relative-pronouns

In the following sentence why is omitting "who was" correct?

> Michelangelo, who was a sculptor, an architect, a painter, and a poet
>   had a great influence on the world of art.

to

> Michelangelo, a sculptor, an architect, a painter, and a poet
>   had a great influence on the world of art.

Comment: Notice that you're also deleting something else besides _who_? And what got deleted in _an architect, a painter, and a poet_? Maybe the same things?

Comment: Soroush, in both versions you badly need a comma after "poet". But having four items makes it a little hard to read correctly in any case. The construction "comma + (omitted relative) + list + comma + main clause" usually has fewer. I would prefer "As a blah-blah-blah, Michaelangelo had...."

Answer (score 0):

It is because in removing "who was" you have converted a *subordinate clause* into an extended *appositive*, in which no verb is necessary or appropriate.